# node js event listeners. Use anonymous callbacks or declared functions for performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, optimization

I'm writing a TCP server in Node.js that handles incoming data from multiple connections.
The server parses the incoming data stream and returns an object which is stored in a database.
I'm trying to do some optimization for performance, and tested two coding practices:

- Snippet 1 uses nested anonymous callbacks.
- Snippet 2 used declared
  functions to replace the anonymous callbacks.

I assumed snippet 2 would be faster, as it avoids the creation of new function object for each new incoming data packet.
However, in real-life it seems that snippet 1 is 20% faster.

Does anyone know why?

Snippet 1:

```
function TcpOnConnection (stream) {
    stream.on("data", function(data) {      
      parseTcp(data,function(err,obj) {             
        if (err) console.log(err.message);
        if (obj) {
           stream.write(obj.returnMsg); 
           storeData(obj);
        }
      });
    });
}
TCPserver.on("connection",TcpOnConnection);
```

Snippet 2:

```
function TcpOnConnection (stream) {
    function  handleParsed(err,obj) {               
      if (err) console.log(err.message);
      if (obj) {
        stream.write(obj.returnMsg);    
        storeData(obj);
      }                 
    }

    function StreamOnData(data) {
      parseTcp(data,handleParsed);              
    }

    stream.on("data", StreamOnData);
}
TCPserver.on("connection",TcpOnConnection);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function declaration doesn't avoid creating a new function object or a closure just because it's a function declaration - they have same mechanics in this regard. And in fact you are not just creating a function object but a regular object too (each function comes with a fresh object that you can reference with `.prototype`, although at least in V8 it seems that it is only created when needed).

Functions are first-class objects, that has a downside of having to create a separate object for each function no matter what.

Make sure that all your functions are either created either in module scope or inside a
function that only executes once per application:

```
function handleParsed( err, obj ) {
  if (err) console.log(err.message);
  if (obj) {
    //What I'm doing here is only possible if 
    //`this` refers to the stream
    //That depends how parseTcp calls the callback
    this.write(obj.returnMsg);
    storeData(obj);
  }
}

function StreamOnData( data ) {
    parseTcp( data, handleParsed );    
}

function TcpOnConnection (stream) {
    stream.on("data", StreamOnData);
}
TCPserver.on("connection",TcpOnConnection);
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. How can "this" refer to "stream" when "stream" only exists inside the "TcpOnConnection" scope? The parseTcp function is not aware of the stream object. At the end of successful parsing, the parseTcp simply calls the "handleParsed" callback.

Comment: @SeppVanRompaey right, `this` should be set to `stream` inside `StreamOnData` though, so maybe you can pass it around from there?

Comment: @SeppVanRompaey `this` depends how a function is called, not on scope. The stream should call the data callback like `.call( this, data )` then `this` will refer to `stream` inside the callback. Much like jQuery or DOM event listeners work by `.calling` with `this` set to the element target of the event.

Comment: Indeed that works. However I see no impact on performance. What is considered best practice in processing many simultaneous events and data. Anonymous callbacks or declared functions?

Comment: @SeppVanRompaey There is a performance improvement even in the simplest case http://jsperf.com/123412341353 . The gap will get wider as you stuff more functions inside a function.

Comment: @SeppVanRompaey it doesn't matter which one you use if you place them inside some other function.